# Could not resolve connect identifier error when connecting remotely

Tags: oracle, iis, connection

I have a web service application.The server ip is .....216. It's a database aware application. The database is in another server with ip ......217. Now when I run the application from 216 it works, I can make requests to the database.I can connect to the database with SqlPlus as well. So no errors. But when I try to run that application remotely, not from within the server it's installed, I get ORA:12154 could not resolve the connect identifier error. What could be the reason for this.
 All the computers are in intranet.The platform of database server is Windows Server2008 R2 and the IIS server is Windows 2003 R2. The remote computer's platform is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give network access permission to the folder where Tnsnames.ora file was. And I also had to register asp.net in IIS. After doing that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is the oracle client installed on the other server?

Is there corresponding entries in tnsnames.ora on the other server?

Comment: On the Linux server, from where I call the application in the remote server(.216), there's no Oracle Client.Must there be one?